# Why ternary expression is not updating the value while if statement is working fine?

Tags: java, conditional-operator, static-variables

I have also tried changing the ternary expression to produce the equivalent result:

**is_balanced = (Math.abs(lh-rh)<=1) ? true:false;**

```
static boolean is_balanced=true;

public static int balHeight(Node node) {
   if(node==null) return 0;
   
   int lh  = balHeight(node.left);
   int rh  = balHeight(node.right);
   
  if(Math.abs(lh-rh)>1) is_balanced = false;
    **// ternary not working here
    // is_balanced = Math.abs(lh-rh) > 1 ? false:true;**
   
   return Math.max(lh,rh)+1;
}
```

Comment: No need of ternery operator for this expression Math.abs(lh-rh) > 1 ? false:true just use is_balanced = ! Math.abs(lh-rh) > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent code would be `is_balanced = Math.abs(lh - rh) > 1 ? false : is_balanced`.

(Or, without the ternary: `is_balanced = is_balanced && Math.abs(lh - rh) <= 1`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code with ternary and without ternary, both produce the same result. This means ternary work as expected.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lh = 5;
    int rh = 10;
    boolean balanced;
    balanced = Math.abs(lh - rh) > 1;
    System.out.println("General Assignment - " + balanced);
    balanced = Math.abs(lh - rh) > 1 ? true : false;
    System.out.println("Ternary Assignment - " + balanced);
  }
}
```

Output -

```
General Assignment - true
Ternary Assignment - true
```